# Unknown Provider Error AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying my hands on angularjs authorization using the [POST](http://nadeemkhedr.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/how-to-do-authorization-and-role-based-permissions-in-angularjs/). My code also includes lazy loading from this [POST](http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/)

The code is having trouble injecting 'permissions' factory to the application. My root directory as below

[image]

app.js:

```
(function()
{
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
    var roleId = 5;
    var permissionList = {};

    myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $controllerProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $compileProvider, $httpProvider)
        {
            myApp.controllerProvider = $controllerProvider;
            myApp.compileProvider    = $compileProvider;
            myApp.routeProvider      = $routeProvider;
            myApp.filterProvider     = $filterProvider;
            myApp.provide            = $provide;

            $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('securityInterceptor');

            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl:'app/login/login.html',
                    resolve:{
                        deps: function($q, $rootScope) {
                            var deferred = $q.defer();
                            // Add dependencies here
                            var dependencies =
                                [

                                    'app/services/services.js',
                                    'app/directives/directives.js',
                                    'app/login/login.js',

                                ];

                            $script(dependencies, function()
                            {
                                // all dependencies have now been loaded by $script.js so resolve the promise
                                $rootScope.$apply(function()
                                {
                                    deferred.resolve();
                                });
                            });

                            return deferred.promise;
                        }
                    },
                    permission: 'login'
                });
        });

    myApp.provider('securityInterceptor', function() {
        this.$get = function($location, $q) {
            return function(promise) {
                return promise.then(null, function(response) {
                    if(response.status === 403 || response.status === 401) {
                        $location.path('partials/unauthorized');
                    }
                    return $q.reject(response);
                });
            };
        };
    });

    // Get User Roles and Permissions from server
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('b1.0/../api/index/user-roles', function(data) {
            userRoles = data;
        });

        $.post('b1.0/../api/index/user-permissions', {roleId:roleId}, function(data) {
            permissionList = data;
        });
    });

    myApp.run(function(permissions) {
        permissions.setPermissions(permissionList)
    });

    // Tried this but still not working
    /*myApp.run(['permissions', function(permissions){
        permissions.setPermissions(permissionList);
    }]);*/

})();
```

appBootstrap.js :

```
$script(['app/app.js'], function()
{
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

appMain.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('mainAppCtrl', function($scope, $location, permissions) {
   $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(scope, next, current) {
        var permission = next.$$route.permission;
        if(_.isString(permission) && !permissions.hasPermission(permission))
            $location.path('/unauthorized');
    });
});
```

services.js:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('permissions', function ($rootScope) {
        var permissionList;
        return {
            setPermissions: function(permissions) {
                permissionList = permissions;
                $rootScope.$broadcast('permissionsChanged')
            },
            hasPermission: function (permission) {
                permission = permission.trim();
                return _.some(permissionList, function(item) {
                    if(_.isString(item.Name))
                        return item.Name.trim() === permission
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

directives.js:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('hasPermission', function(permissions) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if(!_.isString(attrs.hasPermission))
                throw "hasPermission value must be a string";

            var value = attrs.hasPermission.trim();
            var notPermissionFlag = value[0] === '!';
            if(notPermissionFlag) {
                value = value.slice(1).trim();
            }

            function toggleVisibilityBasedOnPermission() {
                var hasPermission = permissions.hasPermission(value);

                if(hasPermission && !notPermissionFlag || !hasPermission && notPermissionFlag)
                    element.show();
                else
                    element.hide();
            }
            toggleVisibilityBasedOnPermission();
            scope.$on('permissionsChanged', toggleVisibilityBasedOnPermission);
        }
    };
});
```

> [Here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/x49wvo) is my uploaded file.

The error i am getting is this

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/unpr?p0=permissionsProvider%20%3C-%20permissions

Could anyone tell me what is going wrong here??

**Update 1:** After declaring myApp once as suggested by @Chandermani now there is this error too

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp

Comment: Did you go to the error link?   "This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly. For example:"  As you have provided a lot of code without specifying where the error occurs I'm not sure where the issue is.

Comment: Yes i have rechecked but that's not the issue i guess

Comment: Must be something to do with Chandermani answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refrence all the files in index.html your referencing only

```
<script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="app/vendor/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="app/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="app/vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="app/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="app/appBootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" rel="javascript" src="app/appMain.js"></script>
```

angular modular dependencies doesn't include the files at run-time, it just resolve the instance, if you want to resolve the files at run-time you should be using something like [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/)

---

Note: don't put `ng-view` on the html body tag itself, create a div inside the body and put `ng-view` on it, because putting it on the body will wipe-out everything else on the `index.html` page

Comment: Recently got another problem after implementing. Do you have any idea of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096305/authorization-service-fails-on-page-refresh-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

I see declaration of `myApp` twice

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
```

appMain.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
```

This would recreate the the module. So the second one should be

`var myApp = angular.module('myApp');`