# Authorization Service fails on page refresh in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Implemented the authorization using the [POST](http://nadeemkhedr.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/how-to-do-authorization-and-role-based-permissions-in-angularjs/)
The problem is when i go to a privileged page say '/admin' it works but when i refresh the page
manually, the admin page is redirecting to the '/unauthorized' page

Permissions service

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('PermissionsService', function ($rootScope,$http,CookieService) {
        var permissionList;
        return {
            setPermissions: function(permissions) {
                permissionList = permissions;
                $rootScope.$broadcast('permissionsChanged')
            },
            getPermissions: function() {
                var roleId = 5
                if(CookieService.getLoginStatus())
                    var roleId = CookieService.getUserData().ROLE_ID;

                return $http.post('api/user-permissions', roleId).then(function(result){
                    return result.data;
                });
            },
            hasPermission: function (permission) {
                permission = permission.trim();
                return _.some(permissionList, function(item) {
                    if(_.isString(item.name))
                        return item.name.trim() === permission
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

hasPermissions directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('hasPermission', function(PermissionsService) {
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                if(!_.isString(attrs.hasPermission))
                    throw "hasPermission value must be a string";

                var value = attrs.hasPermission.trim();
                var notPermissionFlag = value[0] === '!';
                if(notPermissionFlag) {
                    value = value.slice(1).trim();
                }

                function toggleVisibilityBasedOnPermission() {
                    var hasPermission = PermissionsService.hasPermission(value);

                    if(hasPermission && !notPermissionFlag || !hasPermission && notPermissionFlag)
                        element.show();
                    else
                        element.hide();
                }
                toggleVisibilityBasedOnPermission();
                scope.$on('permissionsChanged', toggleVisibilityBasedOnPermission);
            }
        };
    });
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','ngCookies']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider,$httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/module/public/index.html',
            header: 'app/partials/header.html',
            footer: 'app/partials/footer.html'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'app/module/login/login.html',
            header: 'app/partials/header.html',
            footer: 'app/partials/footer.html'
        })
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'app/module/home/home.html',
            header: 'app/partials/header.html',
            footer: 'app/partials/footer.html'
        })
        .when('/register', {
            templateUrl: 'app/module/register/register.html',
            header: 'app/partials/header.html',
            footer: 'app/partials/footer.html'
        })
        .when('/admin', {
            templateUrl: 'app/module/admin/admin.html',
            header: 'app/partials/header.html',
            footer: 'app/partials/footer.html',
            permission: 'admin'
        })
        .when('/unauthorized', {
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/unauthorized.html',
            header: 'app/partials/header.html',
            footer: 'app/partials/footer.html'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('securityInterceptor');
});

myApp.provider('securityInterceptor', function() {
    this.$get = function($location, $q) {
        return function(promise) {
            return promise.then(null, function(response) {
                if(response.status === 403 || response.status === 401) {
                    $location.path('/unauthorized');
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            });
        };
    };
});

myApp.run(function($rootScope, $location, $window, $route, $cookieStore, CookieService, PermissionsService) {
    PermissionsService.getPermissions().then(function(permissionList){
        PermissionsService.setPermissions(permissionList);
    });

    // Check login status on route change start
    $rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
        if(!CookieService.getLoginStatus() && $location.path() != '/register' && $location.path() != '/login') {
            $location.path("/");
            $rootScope.$broadcast('notloggedin');
        }

        if(CookieService.getLoginStatus() && $location.path() == '/login') {
            $location.path("/home");
        }

        var permission = next.$$route.permission;
        if(_.isString(permission) && !PermissionsService.hasPermission(permission))
            $location.path('/unauthorized');

    });

    // Adds Header and Footer on route change success
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (ev, current, prev) {
        $rootScope.flexyLayout = function(partialName) { return current.$$route[partialName] };
    });
});
```

CookieService

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('CookieService', function ($rootScope,$http,$cookieStore) {
        var cookie = {
            data: {
                login: false,
                user: undefined
            },
            saveLoginData: function(user) {
                cookie.data.login = true;
                cookie.data.user = user;
                $cookieStore.put('__iQngcon',cookie.data);
            },
            deleteLoginData: function() {
                cookie.data.login = false;
                 cookie.data.user = undefined;
                 $cookieStore.put('__iQngcon',cookie.data);
            },
            getLoginStatus: function() {
                if($cookieStore.get('__iQngcon') === undefined)
                    return cookie.data.login;

                return $cookieStore.get('__iQngcon').login;
            },
            getUserData: function() {
                return $cookieStore.get('__iQngcon').user;
            }
        };

        return cookie;
    });
```

It seems like the permissions data are lost on page refresh. Is there any other way i can solve the problem? Or is there any problem with the code??

Comment: Isn't that expected behavior?  If you reload the page; then all UI state is lost; it is just like shutting down the app and starting from scratch.  If you want to be able to retain state, you'll have to retain the login information somehow--using cookies is not uncommon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well had to think for some time and made the following change for it to work. It may not be the best practice but ya worked for me. Would appreciate if anyone suggested me a better solution in the comments if found.

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $location, $window, $route, $cookieStore, CookieService, PermissionsService) {
    var permChanged = false;

    PermissionsService.getPermissions().then(function(permissionList){
        PermissionsService.setPermissions(permissionList);
    });

    // Check login status on route change start
    $rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
        console.log('$routeChangeStart');
        if(!CookieService.getLoginStatus() && $location.path() != '/register' && $location.path() != '/login') {
            $location.path("/");
            $rootScope.$broadcast('notloggedin');
        }

        if(CookieService.getLoginStatus() && $location.path() == '/login') {
            $location.path("/home");
        }

        $rootScope.$on('permissionsChanged', function (ev, current, prev) {
            permChanged = true;
        });

        if(CookieService.getLoginStatus() && permChanged) {
            var permission = next.$$route.permission;
            if(_.isString(permission) && !PermissionsService.hasPermission(permission))
                $location.path('/unauthorized');
        }

    });

    // Adds Header and Footer on route change success
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (ev, current, prev) {
        $rootScope.flexyLayout = function(partialName) { return current.$$route[partialName] };
    });
});
```

What i did was wait for the permissions to be set and then use the **permissionChanged** broadcast to set a **permChanged** variable to true and then combined with if user loggedin status and **permchanged** had to check the permissions if had

```
$rootScope.$on('permissionsChanged', function (ev, current, prev) {
                permChanged = true;
            });

            if(CookieService.getLoginStatus() && permChanged) {
                var permission = next.$$route.permission;
                if(_.isString(permission) && !PermissionsService.hasPermission(permission))
                    $location.path('/unauthorized');
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

> when i refresh the page manually, the admin page is redirecting to the
>   '/unauthorized' page

Isn't that expected behavior?  If you reload the page; then all UI state is lost; it is just like shutting down the app and starting from scratch.

> It seems like the permissions data are lost on page refresh. Is there
>   any other way i can solve the problem? Or is there any problem with
>   the code??

If you want to be able to retain UI state after a page reload, you'll have to retain the Login information somehow, such as in a browser cookies.  When the app loads; check for that cookie value.  If it exists, you can load the user info from the database, essentially mirroring a login.

I'd be cautious about storing actual user credentials in a cookie without some type of encryption. 
One approach I've used is to store a unique user key which can be sent to the DB to load user info.  Sometimes this may be a UUID associated with the user,  Avoid using an auto-incrementing primary key because that is easy to change to get access to a different user's account.

Comment: Is it? I thought the app runs once again on page refresh (myApp.run()) function, which means the getPermission get the permissions and sets permissions, this should work right?? In the PermissionService getPermission function i am checking if the user is loggedin , get the role make a request to get the permissions and  set it once i got em?

Comment: I think i found a solution see my answer. What do you think is it a good solution?

Comment: I'll admit I only did a cursory review of your code.  Perhaps you already have code to load up users permissiosn based on cookies or some other way.  What is the CookieService service?  It is referenced in your code, but specifics are not shared.

Comment: Please see my updated question with the code for Cookie service. Thank you for the time by the way.

Comment: I only did a quick review; but it looks like your CookieService is already doing the things I suggest--saving Login credentials as a cookie value.  Assuming that after Login you call the saveLoginData() function to save the credentials; then your approach is probably okay.